# No reply received - perhaps a timeout in the template?

Tags: spring-amqp

I have done following RabbitMQ-Spring configuration for RPC call

Following is the configuration:-

```
/>

<rabbit:queue name="identity.queue" />   
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="identity.exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="identity.queue"  key="identity.binding"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
<bean id="idenityListener"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.remoting.service.AmqpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="<<package>.AA" />
    <property name="service" ref="AAProxy" />
    <property name="amqpTemplate" ref="template" />
</bean>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="idenityListener" queue-names="identity.queue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

At client side:-

/>

<bean id="identityClient"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.remoting.client.AmqpProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="amqpTemplate" ref="identityTemplate" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="<<package>.AA" />
</bean>

<bean id="AAProxy" class="<xx>.AAProxy" init-method="init" />

<rabbit:template id="identityTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="2000"
    routing-key="identity.binding" exchange="identity.exchange" />
```

I am getting the following error while setup for RabbitMQ RPC call. This setup working on same machine and while not working on different machine:-

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteProxyFailureException: No reply received - perhaps a timeout in the template?
            at org.springframework.amqp.remoting.client.AmqpClientInterceptor.invoke(AmqpClientInterceptor.java:60)  


**Log file:-**  

    =ERROR REPORT==== 19-Feb-2015::10:05:59 ===
    Channel error on connection <0.1474.0> (172.16.206.139:59826 -> 172.16.206.154:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'reetesh'), channel 13:
    {amqp_error,not_found,"no queue 'identity.queue' in vhost '/'",
                'queue.declare'}    

Whenever I tried to connect I found following above in log.   



Reetesh
```

Comment: Share, please, the config on the matter. Seems for me `"no queue 'identity.queue' in vhost '/'` is obvious...

Comment: Hi Artem, I added the configuration. have you any idea about error?

Comment: Maybe you user doesn't have enough permissions to create a queue on the Broker ?

Comment: You don't show a rabbit admin (although you did show on in your question on the rabbit-users list). If you do have a rabbit admin; turn on debug logging, we put out lots of information when the queues/bindings etc are declared.

Comment: I already added admin tag in both the places Client and Server    :<rabbit:admin id="amqpAdmin" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for suggestion. Can you please confirm the following is sufficient for enable debug  "rabbitmqctl trace_on" or anything else need to configure.

Answer (score 3):

i had a similar problem, i not fix them. Finally i use "direct reply-to"

See
http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html
3.7.1 section.

with this configuration not needs a fixed reply queue and "reply-listener" is not required and should not be configured.